# Document_Open Macro Won't Start

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-template, vba

I'm using a simple Document_Open macro to display a message box to anyone opening a Word form. This macro worked without a problem until I uploaded it as a document template in a SharePoint 2013 document library. Does anyone know if there's a trick to Document_Open macros working in SharePoint? Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to get a solution to this?

Comment: Nope. Document_New didn't work, either.

Answer (score 0):

After searching around I did find the solution..

Check out the answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787466/disable-save-as-in-word-2013-using-vba/35834498#35834498

Comment: This doesn't quite do it. I ended up giving Application.DocumentChange a try, too, but that code doesn't trigger upon creating a new document from SharePoint.

Comment: When you go into the Advanced settings and click edit template, does the macros fire up?